# custom sort array of data base on value

Tags: javascript

I have Array like this

```
 array = [
 {name: '0:homdel', data: Array(3)},
 {name: '1:LOH', data: Array(5)}, 
 {name: '2:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '2:LOH', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '3-4:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '3-4:LOH', data: Array(5)} ,
 {name: '5-8:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '5-8:LOH', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '9+:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '9+:LOH', data: Array(5)}]
```

How can I sort the array so that the result will become:

```
 sort = 
[{name: '0:homdel', data: Array(3)},
{name: '1:LOH', data: Array(5)},
{name: '2:LOH', data: Array(5)},
{name: '3-4:LOH', data: Array(5)},
{name: '5-8:LOH', data: Array(5)},
{name: '9+:LOH', data: Array(5)},
{name: '2:het', data: Array(5)} ,
{name: '3-4:het', data: Array(5)},
{name: '5-8:het', data: Array(5)} ,
{name: '9+:het', data: Array(5)} ]
```

I have tried array.sort(customSort);

```
function customSort(a, b) {
  let [countA, nameA] = a.name.split(':');
  let [countB, nameB] = b.name.split(':');
  let nameComparison = nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
  let countComparison = parseInt(countA) - parseInt(countB);
  if (nameComparison == 0) {
    return countComparison;
  } else {
    return nameComparison;
  }
 }
```

but the result is not what I expected.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The first is out of order and the second is ordered? It looks the other way around. Also parseInt isn't going to work, not all of those are integers.

Comment: What is the sorting criteria?

Comment: I want to sort base on the word after the colon (:), but keep 0:homdel as the first array

Comment: What is your current result? If you want to treat one value specially, you have to add that somehow to your code. If you want to keep `0:homedel` as first elemen, you could add a condition like `if ( a.name === '0:homedel') return -1` and `if (b.name === '0: homedel') return 1` to your sort function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation in comments. Basically, remove the first element and sort the rest based on a custom tag.

```js
let array = [
 {name: '0:homdel', data: Array(3)},
 {name: '1:LOH', data: Array(5)}, 
 {name: '2:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '2:LOH', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '3-4:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '3-4:LOH', data: Array(5)} ,
 {name: '5-8:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '5-8:LOH', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '9+:het', data: Array(5)},
 {name: '9+:LOH', data: Array(5)}]

const thesort = (arr) => {
  // first grab the obj that is not getting sorted
  let first = arr.shift();
  // add the sortable tag
  let narr = arr.map(a => ({ ...a,
    tag: a.name.split(":")[1]
  }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.tag.localeCompare(a.tag)) // sort it
    .map(a => { delete a.tag; return a }); // remove the custom tag
  narr.unshift(first)
  return narr
}

console.log(thesort(array))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to slice the array and such, but your solution seems to be better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const array = [ {name: '0:homdel'}, {name: '1:LOH'}, {name: '2:het'}, {name: '2:LOH'}, {name: '3-4:het'}, {name: '3-4:LOH'} , {name: '5-8:het'}, {name: '5-8:LOH'}, {name: '9+:het'}, {name: '9+:LOH'} ];

const sorted = array.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => {
  if(b === '0:homdel') return 1;
  else if(a === '0:homdel') return -1;
  const [, nameA] = a.split(':'), [, nameB] = b.split(':');
  return nameB.localeCompare(nameA);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You also need to check `if (a === '0:homdel')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and use some adjustments for the value.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: '0:homdel', data: [] }, { name: '1:LOH', data: [] }, { name: '2:het', data: [] }, { name: '2:LOH', data: [] }, { name: '3-4:het', data: [] }, { name: '3-4:LOH', data: [] }, { name: '5-8:het', data: [] }, { name: '5-8:LOH', data: [] }, { name: '9+:het', data: [] }, { name: '9+:LOH', data: [] }];

array.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => {
    const
        split = s => {
            let [value, text] = s.split(':');
        
            if (value.includes('+')) {
                value = parseInt(value) + .1;
            } else if (value.includes('-')) {
                let v = value.split('-').map(Number);
                value = (v[0] + v[1]) / 2;
            }

            return { value, text };
        },
        aa = split(a),
        bb = split(b);
        order = { homdel: 1, LOH: 2, het: 3 };

    return order[aa.text] - order[bb.text] || aa.value - bb.value
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```